# Libvlc function libvlc_new_callbacks

Tags: c, libvlc, libusb

Hello i am trying to implement this function of libvlc version 3.0, libvlc_new_callbacks to read from a buffer array.  [Documentation](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga591c3cbe56444f1949165b2b9b75d8e2)

I got a function that use libusb to receive usb transfers from a device

```
static void procedimiento_de_llamada_leer_transferencia_usb(struct libusb_transfer *transferencia_usb_2)
{
    if(transferencia_usb_2->status == LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED)             
    {
        std::cout<<"Transferencia completa"<<std::endl;                    
    }
    else std::cout<<"Error: "<<transferencia_usb_2->status<<std::endl;      

    contador_evitar_basura++;                                                 
    if (contador_evitar_basura > 4)                 
    {
        apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS=transferencia_usb_2->buffer;
        variable_archivo_TS.write( (char *)transferencia_usb_2->buffer, tamanio_buffer); 
    }

    int respuesta_transferencia_llamada = libusb_submit_transfer(transferencia_usb_2);  

    if(respuesta_transferencia_llamada != 0) std::cout<<"Error transferencia: "<<respuesta_transferencia_llamada<<std::endl; 
}
```

Actually the transfered  bytes goes to a file and then open that file with libvlc as a media file to reproduce it, with this line instruction i write the bytes received to a file

```
variable_archivo_TS.write( (char *)transferencia_usb_2->buffer, tamanio_buffer);
```

I can see the video in my program but the file is constantly growing, if  a keep watching the video for a long time the file could get sizes of 10 Gb. I am trying to send the buffer that libusb received to the player without saving it in a file, i create a global variable that points to the buffer

```
unsigned char *apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS;

apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS=transferencia_usb_2->buffer;
```

Then i am trying to implement the function of libvlc_new_call_backs:

I pass the pointer **apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS** to the function, and set the callbacks open and read, declare seek and close as a NULL, maybe is a wrong approach but i  am thinking to read all the buffer at once so i don't need a seek function

```
void procedimiento_media_callbacks()
{
    static libvlc_media_t *media = libvlc_media_new_callbacks(
                         instancia_vlc,     // vlc
                         open_callback,     //open media
                         read_callback,     //read media
                                  NULL,     //NULL seak
                                  NULL,     //NULL close
     apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS);    //NULL

    libvlc_media_player_set_media(reproductor, media);
    libvlc_media_add_option(media, funcion_leer_id());    
    libvlc_media_player_set_media(reproductor, media);          

}
```

I am thinking in just using the open_callback function to points data to opaque(buffer) and set sizep to the size of the buffer,

```
int open_callback(void *opaque, void **datap, long unsigned int *sizep)
{
    *sizep = 245760;
    *datap = opaque;
    return 0;
}
```

In the read function i am not sure about this just return the size of data read it

```
long int read_callback(void *opaque, unsigned char *buf,long unsigned int len)
{
    return 245760;
}
```

But i can't get it work, i couldn't find a code that use this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the code how i making it work

```
//! Variable para indicar la posicion del buffer a copiar a la media del reproductor.
/*!
     Posiciones={0,245760,491520,737280,983040,1228800,1474560,1720320,1966080,2211840,2457600,2703360,2949120,3194880,3440640,3686400,3932160,4177920,4423680,4669440}.
*/
static int posicion_media_buffer=0;

//! Función de llamada de la función libvlc_media_new_callbacks para apuntar a la posición de los datos y guardar el tamaño del buffer a leer.
/*!
    \param *opaque apuntador al buffer rotativo.
    \param **datap espacio de alamacenamiento para un apuntador de datos.
    \param *sizep apuntador al tamaño del buffer de datos.
    \return 0 operación exitosa.
*/
int abrir_media(void *opaque, void **datap, long unsigned int *sizep)
{
    *sizep = tamanio_buffer;                                                //Asigna el tamaño de los datos
    *datap = opaque;                                                        //Coloca como data con el apuntador al buffer rotativo
    return 0;                                                               //Devuelve cero
}

//! Función de llamada de la función libvlc_media_new_callbacks para leer los datos.
/*!
    \param *opaque apuntador al buffer rotativo.
    \param *buf apuntador al buffer de lectura.
    \param len longuitud de los datos a leer.
    \return devuelve la cantidad de datos leidos.
*/
long int leer_media(void *opaque, unsigned char *buf,long unsigned int len)
{
    len=tamanio_buffer_MPEG_TS;                                                 //Longuitud de datos a leer igual al tamanio_buffer_MPEG_TS
    std::memcpy(buf,((unsigned char*)opaque+posicion_media_buffer), len);       //copiar los dtoas del buffer rotativo al buffer de lectura
    procedimiento_retardo_milisegundos(2);                                      //Retardo par evitar uso excesivo del CPU
    posicion_media_buffer+=tamanio_buffer_MPEG_TS;                              //Aumentar posición_media_buffer con los datos ya leidos

    if(posicion_media_buffer>4669440||funcion_leer_estado_hotplug()!=1)         //Si posicion_media_buffer mayor a 4669440 ó dispositivo desconectado
        posicion_media_buffer=0;                                                //posicion_media_buffer igual a cero

    return tamanio_buffer_MPEG_TS;                                              //Devuelve la cantidad de datos leidos
}

//! Funcion de llamada de la función libvlc_media_new_callbacks para colocar la nueva posición en el buffer de datos.
/*!
    \param *opaque apuntador al buffer rotativo.
    \param offset posicion de nuevos datos leidos.
    \return 0 operación exitosa.
*/
int posicionar_media(void *opaque, uint64_t offset)
{
    offset=0;   //offset igual a cero
    return 0;   //retorna cero
}

//! Procedimiento procedimiento_media_callbacks.
/*!
    Procedimeinto para obtener la data media y luego mandarlar a reproducir con el reproductor.
*/
void procedimiento_media_callbacks(void)
{
    media = libvlc_media_new_callbacks(     //media igual a los datos BTS que llegan la pueert USB su llenado es asincrónico
                         instancia_vlc,     //Instancia vlc
                           abrir_media,     //función de llamada abrir_media()
                            leer_media,     //función de llamada leer_media()
                      posicionar_media,     //función de llamada posicionar_media()
                                  NULL,     //NULL cerrar media
     apuntador_al_buffer_recepcion_BTS);    //Apuntador al buffer roatativo

    libvlc_media_add_option(media, funcion_leer_id());                                      //Se coloca el ID del canal deseado a reproducir
    libvlc_media_player_set_media(reproductor, media);                                      //Se coloca el medio media en el reporductor
    libvlc_media_player_play(reproductor);                                                  //Reproducir
}
```

Comment: thank you for an example , I'm trying to get this working too, currently unsuccessful but your example is very helpful to move forward